# Need max and min time of day

Tags: php, mysql, max, min

I am having a few issues. 
I want to be able to fetch the minimum [earliest] **(start_time)** and maximum [latest] **(end_time)** of all the *events* put together, however, I only want to select the maximum and minimums of the events that take place on the date below.... ($date0_post)...*[note that I am going to duplicate this seven times, to replicate the style of a week...so the "+0 day" will eventually end up having a function, i.e: "+1 day", "+2 day", etc.]*

```
$date0 = strtotime("+0 day");
$date0_post = date('Y-m-d', $date0);
```

below is an example of how I thought it might work, however, I am sure i am doing it incorrectly:

```
$sql = "SELECT max(end_time), min(start_time) FROM events WHERE date='$date0_post' AND course='$courseid'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
$event_min_start = $row["start_time"];    
$event_max_end = $row["end_time"];
}
```

---

Seperately, I have variable **$coursetee_open_time_mysql** & **$coursetee_close_time_mysql** ...in the datetime format (the same format these max and min are being fetched in)...below is an if statement declaring if: 
**THE MIN-START time for any event for that day is earlier then the opening time for the course & THE MAX-END time for any event for that day is layer than the closing time**, then `echo '<option value="1" disabled>Closed for '.$closed_reason.'</option>';`

```
if ($event_min_start < $coursetee_open_time_mysql && $coursetee_close_time_mysql < $event_max_end) {
echo '<option value="1" disabled>Closed for '.$closed_reason.'</option>';
} else {
echo '<option value="1">Today</option>';
}
```

Comment: Why do you thing you do it incorrectly ? what results you get and what result you expect ?

Comment: If statement comes up as the else echo

Comment: And I have an event scheduled for today, spaning before the opening time and after the closing time (as a test), just as the if statement is instructed to read, and it still is giving me the else echo

Comment: Have you try `print_r()` with `$event_min_start`, `$event_max_end`, `$coursetee_open_time_mysql` and `$coursetee_close_time_mysql` to see what values you have ?

Comment: Have you test your query directly in database ?

Comment: I have, I've tried many different things. I actually found a quick fix...

Answer (score 0):

I was over thinking it, I fixed it and turned three fetches into one...thankyou @hd1 for leading me in the correct dirrection.

```
$sql = "select reason, min(start_time) AS start_time, max(end_time) AS end_time FROM events WHERE date='$date_post' AND course='$courseid'";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
$event_max_end = $row["end_time"];
$event_min_start = $row["start_time"];
$event_reason = $row["reason"];
}
```